# Poker deck simulation in R

Tags: r

I am working on a poker deck prability simulation. I would like to get the probability that player 1 is dealt a hand consisting of a single suit only. 
I got the code below, however, I get the following error:

```
> checkDeck1()
Error in unique(deck[1:4]) : argument "deck" is missing, with no default
```

Code:

```
pokerdeck <- rep(LETTERS[1:4],13) 
deck <- sample(x=pokerdeck, size=13) #Deck of player 1!

checkDeck1 <- function(deck) {
  uniquedeck <- unique(deck[1:13])
  ## if it is only a single suit
  if (length(uniquedeck)==1) {
    rv <- TRUE
  } else {
    rv <- FALSE
  }
  return (rv)
}
checkDeck1()
```

Comment: you need `checkDeck1(deck)`.  Your function could be written more compactly as `checkDeck1 <- function(deck) { length(unique(deck))==1 }` ...

Answer (score 2):

You want to call

```
checkDeck1(deck)
```

In the code of your function checkDeck1, the scope of the variable deck is local - the fact that you name this variable like a global variable locally overwrites it.